# jQuery to regular Javascript - overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, overlay

I've used the following jQuery code to create somewhat of an overlay for my website..

```
$(function() {
var docHeight = $(document).height();
$("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div><div id='my_popup'></div>");
$("#overlay")
  .height(docHeight)
  .css({
     'opacity' : 0.4,
     'position': 'absolute',
     'top': 0,
     'left': 0,
     'background-color': 'black',
     'width': '100%',
     'z-index': 5000
  });
});
```

I'd like to produce the same results, with regular javascript, **no jquery**, how would I start/go about this?

Also the code I'm currently using results in the overlay being re-loaded on every page, where as it should only load on the main page or landing page. Can anyone suggest a fix for that?

Answer (score 3):

Translating directly from jQuery to Vanilla:

```
(function() {
    if (window.location.href.split('/').pop() == "yourlandingpage") {
        var body = document.body,
            html = document.documentElement,
            docHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,             html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

        body.innerHTML += "<div id='overlay'></div><div id='my_popup'></div>";
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = docHeight + "px";
        document.getElementById("overlay").className = "NewClass";
    }
}());
```

And then declare CSS:

```
.NewClass {
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k8xpkbh0/)**

Comment: It will fail with error of course. Watch `appendChild` usage, it expects DOMElement as parameter, not a string. Also don't forget to add `px` units to height value.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, appreciate it, how would I go about making this overlay only display on the homepage, or first page the visitor lands on?

Comment: Can you give me the URL or something similar to the URL to play with? It's relatively easy to make a check for the index page in the conditional

Answer (score 2):

Here is pure javascript/CSS analog of your jQuery overlay:

```
var overlay = "<div id='overlay'></div><div id='my_popup'></div>";
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', overlay);
```

and CSS

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5000;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

Note, that I cheated a little by using `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`, so that I don't need to set overlay height with document height, and can go with simple CSS.

#### Exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/ajwmcbww/

Comment: Thank you for your solution, appreciate it, how would I go about making this overlay only display on the homepage, or first page the visitor lands on?